# How to make API call using struct with number in the json file

Tags: json, api, swiftui

Providing more detail:

I'm trying to access a level from an API (linked below) that has in it's structure, a number at the beginning one of the levels (25th_percentile). I am unable to create a constant in my model because I cannot start the let value with a number (ie, 25 in 25th_percentile).  How can you access the data at the 25th percentile level?

My code is as follows. When I use enum as suggested, I get a "not conforming to decodable protocol" error.

```
     //
 //  SchoolData.swift
 //
 //

 import Foundation

 struct Results: Decodable {
     let results: [SelectedSchool]
 }



 struct SelectedSchool: Decodable, Identifiable {
     let id: Int
     let fed_sch_cd: String
     let latest: LatestData

 }
 struct LatestData: Decodable {
     let school: SchoolDetails
     let admissions: AdmissionsDetails
 }

 struct SchoolDetails: Decodable {
     let name: String
     let school_url: String
 }

 struct AdmissionsDetails: Decodable {
     let admission_rate: AdmissionRateDetails
     let sat_scores: SATScores
 }


 struct SATScores: Decodable {
     let midpoint: SATSubjects
     let the25th_percentile: SATSubjects2

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case the25th_percentile = "25th_percentile"
     }
 }




 struct SATSubjects: Decodable {
     let math: Int?
     let writing: Int?
     let critical_reading: Int?
 }


 struct SATSubjects2: Decodable {
     let math: Int?
     let writing: Int?
     let critical_reading: Int?
 }


 struct AdmissionRateDetails: Decodable {
     let overall: Float?
 }

 struct URLName {
     let partialURL = "https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?school.name="
     var searchTerm: String = ""
     let apiKey = "&api_key=myapikey"
 }
```

[The API converted to JSON.](https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json?school.name=stanford&api_key=myapikey)

Comment: please do not show bits of pictures of code or data.
Show us a real representation of your json data.
From the bit of picture you show, it looks like it's a string not a number.

Comment: So what you want is to give your model attributes a different name than the json's name, without numbers? I don't quite understand your request.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you - I did share the json data and tried to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
struct SATTwentyFive: Decodable {
    let the25th_percentile: SubjectData
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the25th_percentile = "25th_percentile"
    }
}
```

EDIT1:

Try these kind of structs to read your json data (works well for me):

```
struct Results: Decodable {
    let results: [SelectedSchool]
}

struct SelectedSchool: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let fed_sch_cd: String
    let latest: LatestData
}

struct LatestData: Decodable {
    let school: SchoolDetails
    let admissions: AdmissionsDetails
}

struct SchoolDetails: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let school_url: String
}

struct AdmissionsDetails: Decodable {
    let admission_rate: AdmissionRateDetails
    let sat_scores: SATScores
}

// ---- here ----
struct SATScores: Decodable {
    let midpoint: SATSubjects
    let the25th_percentile: SATSubjects

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the25th_percentile = "25th_percentile"
        case midpoint = "midpoint"
    }
}

struct SATSubjects: Decodable {
    let math: Int?
    let writing: Int?
    let critical_reading: Int?
}

struct AdmissionRateDetails: Decodable {
    let overall: Float?
}
```

and decode `Results` like:

```
try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: data)
```

Comment: thanks workingdog - when I do as suggested, I get a not conforming to decodable protocol error.

Comment: The approach in my answer with the `enum CodingKeys` works. 
I have updated my answer. P.S: do not post your secret key, remove it now.

Comment: workingdog - removed API key and THANK YOU!!!! I tried 1000 things, but apparently not the above. really really appreciate your time!!!

Comment: glad it is working. If my answer was of use, could mark it as correct please.

Comment: I did mark it but I don’t have enough “reputation points” for it to accept my mark. It said it noted it somehow. Thank you again.

Comment: oh, I did not know you cannot accept an answer when you post a question. Thanks anyway.